# Timer Event Called When Run Locally But Not On Server Machine

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I'm working on a windows service that imports files into a database system on a 5 second interval. When I run this service on my local machine everything runs normally but when I copy it onto the server and run it the timer event doesn't get called.

**Code:**

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(Timer_Tick), null, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5), new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5));
        EventLog.WriteEntry("Timer started.", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information);
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object s)
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry("Timer ticking.", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information);
    }
```

Simply put, the "Timer started" is logged but not the "Timer ticking" when the service is run on the server.

**Stack:**
[image: stack trace]

Why is it unable to find the method?

Could this be a .net version issue?

Comment: Are you sure the service has permission to write to the event log on the server?

Comment: That's not what your real code looks like of course.  System.Timers.Timer is a very, *very* nasty class.  Microsoft created it because programmers could not figure out how to use System.Threading.Timer correctly.  It does everything that the "good" timer class does not do.  Including catching exceptions without crashing the program.  They are just swallowed, you'll have no idea that anything went wrong.  Very nasty.  Don't use it.

Comment: I was using System.Threading before but I changed it to see if it would make a difference since I figured it was something to do with the event.

Comment: @Brendan, "Timer started" is being logged so I doubt that's the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my co-worker found that it was a .net version issue. If you are having this problem try compiling your solution with a different target version of .net.